# CUDA dynamic parallelism and global memory synchronization

Tags: cuda

I can't figure out the following.

If I launch a kernel and consider, for example, thread `0` in block `0`, after a `__syncthreads()` call, will all the other threads in all the other blocks see the changes made to global memory by thread `0` in block `0`?

My guess is no. Indeed, in the the [synchronization functions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#synchronization-functions) Section of the CUDA C Programming Guide, it is stated that:

> `void __syncthreads();`
>   waits until *all threads in the thread block* have reached this point and all global and shared memory accesses made by these threads prior to `__syncthreads()` are visible to *all threads in the block*.

However, when talking about [global memory consistency](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#global-memory) in dynamic parallelism, the CUDA C Programming Guide states that:

> Those modifications become available to the other threads of the *parent grid* only after the second `__syncthreads()` call.

So does `__syncthreads()` also makes the changes available across blocks when dynamic parallelism is involved?

Thanks

Comment: Concerning your first question, your conclusion is correct since CUDA does not allow a robust way to enable synchronization across blocks. There is a discussion on the NVIDIA forum entitled [Synchronize all blocks in CUDA](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/526338/cuda-programming-and-performance/synchronize-all-blocks-in-cuda/) which may be of your interest.

Comment: Concerning memory consistency and referring to the specific example you are mentioning, I think that the guide is simply saying that you need the first `__synchthreads()` to ensure that global memory of parent and child kernel are consistent, since all device-side kernel launches are asynchronous (this is mentioned in the CUDA Dynamic Parallelism Programming Guide). The second `__synchthreads()` call is needed to ensure global memory consistency between the kernels inside the same thread block since launched child kernels may take different processing times to finish.

Comment: Take a look at `__threadfence_system()` in [Memory Fence Functions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions) for a way to make something written by one thread visible on the entire device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only action performed by `__syncthreads()` is that quoted by yourself described in the CUDA C Programming Guide. There is no way in CUDA to synchronize across blocks, apart from the naive approach of dividing the execution of a kernel in multiple kernel launches, with all the drawbacks in terms of performance. Accordingly, the answer to your first question, as also guessed by yourself, is NO.

In the second part of your post, you are referring to a specific example of the CUDA C Programming Guide, namely

```
__global__ void child_launch(int *data) {
    data[threadIdx.x] = data[threadIdx.x]+1;
}

__global__ void parent_launch(int *data) { 
    data[threadIdx.x] = threadIdx.x;

    __syncthreads();

    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        child_launch<<< 1, 256 >>>(data);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    }

    __syncthreads();
}

void host_launch(int *data) {
    parent_launch<<< 1, 256 >>>(data);
}
```

Here, all the `256` threads of the `parent_launch` kernel write something in `data`. After that, thread `0` invokes `child_launch`. The first `__syncthreads()` is needed to ensure that all the memory writes have completed before that child kernel invokation. Quoting the guide on this point:

> Due to the first `__syncthreads()` call, the child will see `data[0]=0`, `data[1]=1`, ..., `data[255]=255` (without the `__syncthreads()` call, only `data[0]` would be guaranteed to be seen by the child).

Regarding the second `__syncthreads()`, the Guide explains that

> When the child grid returns, thread `0` is guaranteed to see modifications made by the threads in its child grid. Those modifications become available to the other threads of the parent grid only after the second `__syncthreads()` call.

In that specific example, the second `__syncthreads()` is redundant since there is an implicit synchronization due to the kernel termination, but the second `__syncthreads()` becomes needed when other operations must be performed following the child kernel launch.

Finally, concerning the sentence you are quoting in your post:

> Those modifications become available to the other threads of the parent grid only after the second `__syncthreads()` call

please, note that in the specific example there is only one thread block launched by the `host_launch` function. This perhaps may have somewhat misled you.

There is an interesting discussion (probably even more than one) on the NVIDIA Forum on thread synchronization across blocks entitled

[Synchronize all blocks in CUDA](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/526338/cuda-programming-and-performance/synchronize-all-blocks-in-cuda/)