# Dynamic parallelism cudaDeviceSynchronize() crashes

Tags: cuda

I have a kernel which calls another **empty** kernel. However when the calling kernel calls cudaDeviceSynchronize(), the kernel crashes and the execution goes straight to the host. Memory checker does not report of any memory access issues.
Does anyone know what could be the reason for such uncivilized behavior?

**The crash seems to happen only if I run the code from the debugger** (Visual Studio -> Nsight -> Start CUDA Debugging).
The crash does not happen every time I run the code - sometimes it crashes, and sometimes it finishes ok.

Here is the complete code to reproduce the problem:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define CUDA_RUN(x_, err_) {cudaStatus = x_; if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {fprintf(stderr, err_ "  %d - %s\n", cudaStatus, cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus)); int k; scanf("%d", &k); goto Error;}}

struct computationalStorage {
    float rotMat;
};

__global__ void drawThetaFromDistribution() {}

__global__ void chainKernel() {
    computationalStorage* c = (computationalStorage*)malloc(sizeof(computationalStorage));
    if (!c) printf("malloc error\n");
    c->rotMat = 1.0f;

    int n = 1;
    while (n < 1000) {
        cudaError_t err;

        drawThetaFromDistribution<<<1, 1>>>();
        if ((err = cudaGetLastError()) != cudaSuccess)
            printf("drawThetaFromDistribution Sync kernel error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        printf("0");
        if ((err = cudaDeviceSynchronize()) != cudaSuccess)
          printf("drawThetaFromDistribution Async kernel error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        printf("1\n");
        ++n;
    }

    free(c);
}

int main() {
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    CUDA_RUN(cudaSetDevice(0), "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");

    // Set to use on chip memory 16KB for shared, 48KB for L1
    CUDA_RUN(cudaDeviceSetCacheConfig ( cudaFuncCachePreferL1 ), "Can't set CUDA to use on chip memory for L1");
    // Set a large heap
    CUDA_RUN(cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, 1024 * 10 * 192), "Can't set the Heap size");

    chainKernel<<<10, 192>>>();
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("Something was wrong! Error code: %d", cudaStatus);
    }

    CUDA_RUN(cudaDeviceReset(), "cudaDeviceReset failed!");

Error:
    int k;
    scanf("%d",&k);
    return 0;
}
```

If all goes well I expect to see:

```
00000000000000000000000....0000000000000001
1
1
1
1
....
```

This is what I get when everything works ok. When it crashes however:

```
000000000000....0000000000000Something was wrong! Error code: 30
```

As you can see the statement `err = cudaDeviceSynchronize();` does not finish, and the execution goes straight to the host, where its `cudaDeviceSynchronize();` fails with unknown error code (30 = cudaErrorUnknown).

System: CUDA 5.5, NVidia-Titan(Headless), Windows 7x64, Win32 application.
UPDATE: additional Nvidia card driving the display, Nsight 3.2.0.13289.

Comment: At a first glance, you could be missing a synchronization instruction before the child kernel launch. Furthermore, in the guide to dynamic parallelism, it is said that "For device-side exceptions, e.g., access to an invalid address, an error in a child grid will be returned to the host instead of being returned by the parent’s call to `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`." You are not showing what the child kernel is doing. Perhaps, the best would be the you show the "minimum sized" code reproducing the problem so that someone could compile and run and possibly help.

Comment: "an error in a child grid will be returned to the host" - Wow! Ok, that explains the "strange" behavior.

"you could be missing a synchronization instruction before the child kernel launch" - could you explain what you mean?

"show the "minimum sized" code reproducing the problem" - obviously this would be best, but the code is so extremely complex and involved, that honestly I can't image downsizing it effectively at this stage. If all else fails I would have no choice.

Comment: `suspect_kernel` is using `c` and `distribution` which perhaps are calculated in the `chainKernel` as they are not passed as parameters to the `__global__` function. You should then ensure that all global or shared memory writes are accomplished before the child kernel launch in order to ensure memory coherency between parent and child kernel. This can be done by a `__syncthreads()` call before the child kernel invocation. You are not showing the code before the child kernel launch, therefore this is only speculation for now.

Comment: For further details on ensuring global memory coherency between parent and child kernel you can have a look at CUDA Dynamic Parallelism Programming Guide. In particular, you can refer to the specific example addressed by the second answer to the post [CUDA dynamic parallelism and global memory synchronization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740960/cuda-dynamic-parallelism-and-global-memory-synchronization/19758944#19758944). Reading the guide, you will also be aware that there may be other reasons to require specific synchronization, this depending on the details of your code.

Comment: @JackOLantern: Thank you. In my case however the child kernel uses only the global memory which was written to by the parent kernel. So according to the programming guide:
"All global memory operations in the parent thread prior to the child grid's invocation are visible to the child grid.", I don't need additional synchronization instructions (and shared memory isn't accessible by the child thread anyway).

Comment: What happens when you run your code with `cuda-memcheck` ?  I agree with JackOLantern, there's simply not enough to go on in the snippets you've posted.  A full reproducer would be best.  SO expects:  "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. "  Voting to close.  You haven't provided a SSCCE.org code.

Comment: I have edited the original code and added a complete code needed to reproduce the problem.

Please note an important detail I omitted earlier - this seems to be only reproduced when I debug the device (I haven't been able to reproduce it otherwise yet).

Comment: @Robert Crovella: I'm running with cuda-memcheck

Answer (score 1):

That last fact may have been the critical one.  You don't mention which version of nsight VSE you are using nor your exact machine config (e.g. are there other GPUs in the machine, if so, which is driving the display?), but at least [up till recently](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/536202/debugging-dynamic-parallelism-and-preemption-mode/) it was not possible to debug a dynamic parallelism application in single-GPU mode with nsight VSE.

The [current feature matrix](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition-requirements) also suggests that single-GPU CDP debugging is not yet supported.

Probably one possible workaround in your case would be to add another GPU to drive the display, and make the Titan card headless (i.e. don't attach any monitors and don't extend the windows desktop onto that GPU).

I ran your application with and without cuda-memcheck and it does not appear to me that there are any problems with it.

Comment: Updated the original post. The Titan is headless, Nsight is current.

Comment: Which NVIDIA GPU driver are you using?

Comment: GeForce Desktop (327.23) 64bit

Comment: Can you try [331.65](http://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/331.65/331.65-desktop-win8-win7-winvista-64bit-english-whql.exe)?

Comment: With 331.65 the situation got better. It doesn't crash as readily, so I put the kernel invocation in a loop:

    `begin:
        chainKernel<<<10, 192>>>();
        cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
            printf("Something was wrong! Error code: %d", cudaStatus);
            goto Error;
        } else goto begin;`

It takes now up to several minutes and then it crashes in the same place, but with error 4, instead of 30.